# Using Apache UIMA ConceptMapper in a "proof-of-concept mode"

Tags: java, nlp, uima

I'm trying to use UIMA ConceptMapper to extract some key concepts and other interesting metadata from text documents. **Due to the time constraints of the project** and the fact that I'm not sure if UIMA ConceptMapper will work in this scenario, does anyone know of any quick way to create a basic program using ConceptMapper? That is, can I get away with a quick proof-of-concept without having to write:

- Analysis engine descriptor
- Different structures, interfaces, etc.
- other various meta-stuff

just to see what it can annotate from a single document? Obviously, if it works on a proof-of-concept level, then the long-term plan is to have all those structures in place...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Ruta benchmark](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html)? It will let you quickly prototype with [WORDTABLE and WORDLIST](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.external_resources), similar to what ConceptMapper can do.